# Enabling performance config setting in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When trying to enable the [performance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#performance) setting in Vue 3 I get the following error:

`TypeError: can't access property "performance", app.config is undefined`

My entry point (`main.js`) looks like this:

```js
import App from './App.vue';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const app = createApp(App).mount('#app');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.config.performance = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to `mount` not returning an app instance.

Solution:

```js
const app = createApp(App);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.config.performance = true;
}

app.mount('#app');
```